# How do I change the font size of the labels for a bar graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found another post that indicated that you should grab the current axes of the bar graph and then do the following to change the font size:

```
plt.barh(names, counts, color=colorList)
```

However, when I did this I just get a weird "error" message in the console:

```
No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.
```

Here is my full sample code. I'm trying to change the size of the labels of the bar graph (i.e. the "fruits" in this example):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

colorList = ['#e58725', '#04314e', '#176a94', '#176a94', '#176a94']
names = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Cherry']
counts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

figure(figsize=(8.32,5.1))
plt.barh(names, counts, color=colorList)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize=25)
     
plt.title("My Title", fontsize=20, y=1.03)
plt.grid(visible=None)

plt.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks(font='Roboto', fontsize=10)

plt.savefig('Testing.png')
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Btw you really should be using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.32,5.1))`

Comment: The error comes from the call to `ax.legend(...)`. You didn't "label" elements to put into the legend.  E.g, `plt.barh(names, counts, color=colorList, label='barplot')`. If the barplot is the only element in the plot, the legend doesn't add useful information, so you 'd better remove the call to `ax.legend()`.

Comment: The "fruits" are shown as the "y tick labels".  You can change their size e.g. via `plt.yticks(font='Roboto', fontsize=20)` (supposing you have a 'Roboto' font installed). You might also need `plt.tight_layout()` to let matplotlib fit the labels nicely into the surrounding figure.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is shown because the legend() function is called, but you haven't defined any labels for the plot elements that should appear in the legend. If your bar chart doesn't need a legend, you can simply remove the line `ax.legend()`. But if you do want to show legend, you need to assign labels to your plot elements. Here's how you can add labels to your bar plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

colorList = ['#e58725', '#04314e', '#176a94', '#176a94', '#176a94']
names = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Cherry']
counts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

figure(figsize=(8.32,5.1))
bars = plt.barh(names, counts, color=colorList)


# Assign labels for each bar (for the legend)
for bar, name in zip(bars, names):
    bar.set_label(name)
    
ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize=10)
     
plt.title("My Title", fontsize=20, y=1.03)
plt.grid(visible=None)

plt.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
plt.xticks([])

plt.yticks(font='Roboto', fontsize=10)
plt.show()

plt.savefig('Testing.png')
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Matplotlib, you can change the font size of labels for a bar graph using the fontsize parameter within the set_xlabel and set_ylabel functions. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
# Sample data
categories = ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C', 'Category D']
values = [20, 35, 30, 15]
    
# First create a bar graph
plt.bar(categories, values)
    
# Set labels and title
plt.xlabel('X-Axis Label', fontsize=12)     # Adjust fontsize as needed
plt.ylabel('Y-Axis Label', fontsize=12)     # Adjust fontsize as needed
plt.title('Bar Graph Example', fontsize=16) # Adjust fontsize as needed
   
# Show the plot
plt.show()
```